# Check caller permission dynamically in Service

Tags: android

I have a service in which I want to dynamically check if the caller has the necessary permission to start this service. I noticed that the caller id is always the app in which the service is defined, and not the actual id of the app that's using the service (I confirmed this by calling the getCallingUid() and getCallingPid() methods in onStartCommand()). Where am I supposed to perform this check if not in onStartCommand()? How should I go about doing this?

```
public class MyService extends Service {
        @Nullable
        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
            Log.d("TAG", "uid: " + getCallingUid() + " pid: " + getCallingPid());
int hasPermission = checkCallingPermission(MainActivity.CUSTOM_PERMISSION);
            if (hasPermission  == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return flags;
        }
}
```

Comment: A `Service` can be defined with a [`permission` attribute](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element.html#prmsn) in the manifest.  Why do you want to check this dynamically?

Comment: The problem is that I want to get the caller app's id, and not the id of the app that hosts that service. With the above code, pid, and uid are always from the app in which the service is implemented.

Comment: I think you missed the poinf of my earlier comment.  If `onStartCommand` is called, then you already know that the caller has the required permission.

Comment: That happens only if you're using static permissions. In my case, I need to use dynamic permissions.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to achieve this for me was through the use of Bound Services using AIDL. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12318930/4151895) is how to get started on that. It doesn't work if you call `Binder.getCallingPid()` in onBind, you have to call it in the stub for your interface:

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    private final IMyAidlInterface.Stub mBinder = new IMyAidlInterface.Stub() {
        @Override
        public void myMethod() {
            //PID
            int pid = Binder.getCallingPid();
            Log.d("ITestService in AIDL", String.format("Calling pid in service: %d", pid));
        }
    };
}
```

And this is how the interface looks like:

```
interface IMyAidlInterface {
    /**
     * Demonstrates some basic types that you can use as parameters
     * and return values in AIDL.
     */
    void myMethod();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to provide the Service functionality using a Messenger then `onStartCommand()` and `onBind()` are not appropriate because they are only called for the first client.  This answer may be helpful to you:

[Implementing an exported Android Service for use by an App using <uses-permission-sdk-23>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75611426/implementing-an-exported-android-service-for-use-by-an-app-using-uses-permissio)